# How to pre-allocate max heap space on Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an image processing app that needs a lot of heap space, and am sending these images over the wire. The problem is that each image results in message like

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 16.38M for 1536000 byte allocation
```

This growing seems to be taking a long time, since when I send the images from a computer it takes 1 second, but with my android app it take about 1 minute 30 seconds.

My question is, is there a way to pre-allocate the max heap size so that the heap doesn't have to keep growing?

Comment: How are you sending the image through the net? Are you trying to load all the image into memory first and then write to output buffer? If that's so, then you're using the wrong approach, my friend.

Comment: The image is in memory because I am getting from an opencv camera listener. I am then converting the opencv camera frames to byte arrays because the opencv frames are not serializable. Also I am sending the byte[] using Apache's XmlRpc framework, which sends the array as base64 in chunks of 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is there a way to pre-allocate the max heap size so that the heap doesn't have to keep growing?

I don't think so.  Reading through the Android memory management [article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) reveals nothing.

In classic Java, you can set an initial heap size to avoid the performance overhead of continually growing the heap.  But the assumption on Android seems to be that you should be trying to minimize memory usage at all times.

You might get some "joy" if you simply allocate a very large array and immediately make it unreachable.  The GC should grow the heap so that it can hold the array ... and the space occupied by the array will typically be recycled and made available on the next GC cycle.  On the other hand, when the GC reclaims a huge amount of memory, it might shrink the heap to give most of the space back to the operating system.

---

Having said that, you would probably be advised to change your app so that it doesn't *need* to hold lots of images in memory.  It sounds to me like you might have a memory leak of some type.  Read these links:

- https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html
- https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful response. I don't think I have a memory leak since this occurs even when I have only 1 image in memory and it grows the heap to around 16-17 mb each time. The reason only 1 is in memory is because I am have the images in the native heap space and then I am converting them one at a time to serialize them. I also checked this in the Eclipse heap and allocation viewer.